# leafletjs adding scrollable pop up?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, leaflet

Using leafletjs with popups. When I have popups with minimal text all works fine. If I make them bigger they still work fine. If I add too much I add

```
maxHeight
```

to the pop up and it makes the pop up scrollable.

If I start with out enough content to fill the page and make it scrollable, it is not made scrollable. That is Ok till I dynamically add more content to the popup and then I need the scroll bar but it will not show up.

Any thoughts on how to get leafletjs to add the scroll bar to a popup once the popup has already been rendered?

EDIT: The popup options are initialized with the markers in a loop that loads different arrays of data depending on what a person wants to see. The initialization is as follows.

```
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
        marker.bindPopup('<img width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'"  src="'+a[3]+'"/><br><div id="weather"> <button type="button" onclick="weatherload(\''+a[0]+'\',\''+a[1]+'\')">Click Me for Weather!</button></div>',{'maxWidth':'500','maxHeight':'350','minWidth':'350'});
        CAMlayer.addLayer(marker);
```

The popup has an image that takes up most of the space. At the bottom there is a div with a button. When the button is clicked it is replaced with a loader gif while an ajax function gets some data that it puts in the popup by way of innerhtml.

```
 document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

I set the maxheigth to 350px, once the extra data is added it grows to 520px with no scroll bar.

EDIT: Removed test page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you initialize your popup options and how to you add more content to it?

Once the `maxHeight` option is set, the scroll bar should appear as soon as the content is too big, and disappear as soon as it gets small enough.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/92/

---

**EDIT:**

Following the extra details and code about how you add content to the popup element:

The `height` CSS attribute (which makes the scroll bar appear if necessary) is dynamically added by Leaflet when it detects that the content is too big.

***However*, this detection occurs *only* if you use the `setContent` popup method.** It is not triggered if you change the content through external function (like your AJAX callback in `weatherload` function that "manually" changes a part of the popup content `innerHTML`).

The easiest workaround is simply to call `myPopup._updateLayout()` internal Leaflet method on your popup, just after you have added content. This will "manually" force Leaflet to check the popup content height, and add the `height` CSS attribute if necessary.

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/93/

A "proper" solution would be to avoid adding content through `innerHTML`. Instead, you should use [`setContent` popup method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-setcontent) to update your content (you would copy your initial image, and add your new content). This would also avoid using a div with an ID that is the same for all your popups (which relies on the fact that only 1 popup would be open on the map at any one time, but would break if this assumption is no longer true).

Comment: Updated question. Looking at your fiddle, which works as I thought mine should, I am starting to wonder if I am messing up the initialization, but do not see how

Comment: I see, thank you for the additional details, code and link to a demo that shows the issue. I will edit the above answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If your popup is smarter(is doing 'hard work') I recommend to compile a new directive on the fly.

```
            var newScope = $scope.$new();
            var myPopupContent = $compile('<div style="width:200px"  gr-my-popup ></div>')(newScope);

            L.popup()
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)                  
                .setContent(myPopupContent[0])
                .openOn(map);
```

Where grMyPopup will be your directive.