# Adding an image inside popup content with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

after searching deeper in many questions and in many examples I couldn't get it working. I've trying anything written in any example.

I want to add an image inside a popup marker without using the amazing [Leaflet.photo](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo) plugin this time.

My problem is that the image goes away from the popup boundaries the first time I open it out. After closing it and open it again, the image fits perfectly within the boundaries.

The same as it happens in this example [example](http://bl.ocks.org/uafrazier/d589caa322f1b1e7c651)

I also tryed to hack the CSS class in following way instead of write custom options as in the example source code.

```
.leaflet-popup-content img { max-width:234px !important; height:auto; width:auto !important; }
```

Nothing changed though, the result is the same as in the example shown.
Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

What *may* happen is that the image takes some time to download, hence Leaflet does not know the correct size to give to the popup container.

Then on second opening, the image is fetched from browser cache, and Leaflet can properly compute the popup size.

You can try a delayed `myPopup._updateLayout()` call to have Leaflet re-evaluate the popup container size once your image is downloaded. E.g. attach an onload listener to your image element, with a callback that calls the `_updateLayout()` method on the popup.

See also [leafletjs adding scrollable pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469574/leafletjs-adding-scrollable-pop-up)

Comment: my image element is embebed in the bindPopup marker method:
    desc = desc + "<br><img src=" + "'" + feature.properties.imag + "'" + "/>" + "<br>Ph: Marcelo Giaccino"; 

    var marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon:       patrimonioIcon}).bindPopup(desc).addTo(mapa);

Since I am pretty new with JS, HTML5, I need to dig deeper to do that.
I appreciate any suggestions though :)

Comment: Finally I got it working, I set an id for the image element and a load jquery function. I put it inside the  marker.on('click', function() to delay the updateLayout since it is where the popup is open.
The load query calls for popup._updateLayout() method. 
I used the $('#imgID').load method since I don't want the image loaded if it is in the caché.